# Is my interpretaion of Hobbes correct?

Tags: grammar

> Forasmuch as whosoever speaketh to another, intendeth thereby to make him understand what he saith; if he speak unto him, either in a language which he that heareth understandeth not, or use any word in other sense than **he believeth is the sense of him that heareth**; he intendeth also to make him not understand what he saith; **which is a contradiction of himself**. It is therefore always to be supposed, that **he which intendeth not to deceive, alloweth the private interpretation of his speech to him to whom it is addressed**.

I don't understand the bold parts.

"or use any word in other sense than this listener's understanding of the word."
**he** believeth is the sense of **him** that heareth.
This he is the speaker and him is the listener?

"which means this speaker is contradicting himself, because he wants the listener to understand him but at the same time he doesn't want the listener to understand him"

"people who don't want to deceive people allow what they say to be understood by the listener"

Is this correct?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting a literary work. But yes, your interpretation is how I understand the text, too.

Comment: _alloweth the private interpretation of his speech to him to whom it is addressed._ What an opaque statement

Comment: @username901345, that doesn’t make it on-topic. Interpretation of what passages in literary texts, poetry, lyrics, etc., mean is considered off-topic as per the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If there is a specific phrasing or word that you do not understand, you can edit the question to highlight what it is; but as it stands now, it is off-topic.

Comment: What it clearly means is that anyone not intending to deceive will give his message in a form that he knows the addressee will understand. If a French person complains to an English hotel manager that he was given 'lard' to eat with his eggs for breakfast, knowing very well that the French word 'lard' means 'bacon' in English - then he is intent on deceit.  Or something like that!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But this is not a 'literary' text in the common acceptance of that term: it is from a discussion of linguistic pragmatics. Its English is difficult for a modern reader to follow, so OP quite properly comes here for elucidation; but it is no more off-topic than a passage from Grice.

Comment: I think if anyone wants to read Hobbes *in the original words* it's incumbent on them to ensure they understand archaic English in the first place. OP clearly doesn't understand the way Hobbes uses ***allow*** here. It's not the standard current meaning of *permit, let* - more *acknowledge, sanction* (and by implication in context, ***use***). Essentially, the passage says *"If you want to **communicate** rather than **mislead**, only use words (and meanings thereof) which are familiar to your audience"*.

Answer (score 1):

> Forasmuch as whosoever speaketh to another, intendeth thereby to make him understand what he saith; if he speak unto him, either in a language which he that heareth understandeth not, or use any word in other sense than he believeth is the sense of him that heareth; he intendeth also to make him not understand what he saith; which is a contradiction of himself. It is therefore always to be supposed, that he which intendeth not to deceive, alloweth the private interpretation of his speech to him to whom it is addressed.

A slightly more up-to-date phrasing/slight paraphrasing of this (I left the semicolons alone because I think it is easier to follow with them in):

> Someone speaking to another, intending to make them understand; If he speaks to them in either a language they don't understand, or uses words that the other person could misinterpret; he also intends to be misunderstood; he contradicts himself. It follows then that he who intends no deception is unambiguous in his choice of words, or if not, assumes the interpretation of them as that of the listener.

The point is that someone who genuinely wishes to be understood uses language that is familiar to the listener and they use the familiar meanings of those words rather than unfamiliar e.g. the pun 'I'm feeling a little hoarse/horse' would be readily misinterpreted by someone unaware of the word hoarse.

Comment: @username901345 he who intends no deception (i.e. speaks truthfully) uses words in contexts that the recipient is familiar with. I tried to indicate an example of deliberate confusion, for humorous purposes, in my answer.

Your mention of 'allow what they say to be understood' is not quite correct. It is more that they choose to use words they know the listener will understand.

Comment: The problem is that the paragraph is dealing with the differences between 'what I said,' 'what you thought I said' and 'what I meant', and it is very difficult to retain that meaning in this sentence through a literal translation. Perhaps, 'He who intends no deception allows for (semantically different from allows; more like 'considers that') the person understanding something different to what he meant.' With the implication that the speaker changes their speech to minimise the disparity.